# How to get html output for variable?

Tags: javascript, html

I have such a script (changed and easyfied for better understanding):

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var summary;

function validateSteps(stepnumber){
if(stepnumber == 1){
...
var resultStep1 = '<b>Shape1: </b>' + $('#chooseshape1').val();
summary = resultStep1;}

if(stepnumber == 2){
...
var resultStep2 = '<b>Shape2: </b>' + $('#chooseshape2').val();
summary += resultStep2;}

if(stepnumber == 3){
...
var resultStep3 = '<b>Shape3: </b>' + $('#chooseshape3').val();
summary += resultStep3;}
}

$('#resultSteps').val(summary);

}
```

I get no output for `#resultSteps`

Only when I write `$('#resultSteps').text(summary);` I get output in that div but it looks like:

```
<b>Shape1: </b>round, <b>Shape2: </b>square<b>Shape3: </b>rectangle
```

But I want output like this:

**Shape1:** round **Shape2:** sqaure **Shape3:** rectangle

How to achieve this?

Comment: `.val` is for inputs, use `.html`/`.text` to get/set content in elements like div, span etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("#resultSteps").html(summary);
```

Comment: Worked like a charme. Thank you both for advise. Sometimes you dont see the forrest just because of too many trees in front of you.

Comment: I already tried to check I get an error message that it is possible in 5 minutes. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Use `.html` which outputs the elements as they should be, so `<b>text</b>` would become **text**.

```
 $("#resultSteps").html(summary);
```

`.val` wouldn't work as I presume `#resultSteps` is not an input-field.
`.text` would probably remove the tags (`<b>`).

[Docs](https://api.jquery.com/html/)